# how to multiply all elements in a sequence but in each iteration to omit the current element (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example: If we have `array = [1,2,5,10];`
output should be `[100,50,20,10];`

So, in each iteration escape the current element of iteration.

Comment: What? How do you get from the first array to the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first find the total product and then divide that by the current element in each iteration.

```js
const arr = [1,2,5,10];
const product = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc*curr,1);
const res = arr.map(x => product / x);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion

```
[1,2,5,10].map((x, i, arr) => arr.reduce((acc, y, j) => (i !== j) ? acc * y : acc, 1));
```